# $f(x, y) = \prod_{i = 1}^n (1 + xy_i)$, what is ${{{\partial f}\over{\partial x}}\over f}$, geometric series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Let$$f(x, y) = \prod_{i = 1}^n (1 + xy_i).$$What is$${{{\partial f}\over{\partial x}}\over f}?$$What happens when we use the geometric series?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$\frac{\partial \ln f}{\partial x}={{{\partial f}\over{\partial x}}\over f}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{\frac{∂f}{∂x}}{f}$ is equal to $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}[\ln(f)]$.

Meanwhile, $\ln(f)$ would be the series $\Sigma_{i=1}^n [1 + x y_i]$.

Thus $\frac{\frac{∂f}{∂x}}{f}= \Sigma_{i=1}^n y_i$. (Since partial derivatives commute with finite sums.)

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_derivative